# "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" on Alexa Simulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to setup a sample Alexa skill set with sample 'hello world' lambda function. But when testing on Alexa simulator, showing `There was a problem with the requested skills response` as shown in below.
[image]

I have created a sample Alexa skill set and connected with AWS lambda function using ARN in endpoint section.

Answer (score 2):

**"There was a problem with the requested skill's response”** means that there is something wrong with the response json from the Lambda function. It might be null or invalid.

In your case, check the `LaunchRequest` handler for any issues.

A sample `LaunchRequest` handler in **ask-nodejs-sdk-v2** will be like:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log('Inside LaunchRequestHandler');
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Welcome to my ABC skill')
      .reprompt('Welcome to my ABC skill')
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Comment: There was nothing wrong with mine, but I looked over the JSON file and I was not saying one of its expected lines. So when I tried Alexa again and said it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is throwing in your Lambda code. Since you've deployed to Lambda, you could check the CloudWatch logs for any error messages. This will help you rather than debugging blind.

It might also worth setting up some way to run and debug the code locally too.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to debug this issue is **copying the input JSON** from Alexa skill simulator and paste it in the **lambda's configure test events**. Now run **test** and it'll generate all the **error logs** in the lambda itself, for your easy reference.

If you've no clue on the error log, edit your question with the logs so that some experienced people could help. Thanks.

Comment: How does one access "lambda's configure test events" from skill test page?